# Lithium ion battery pack busbar thermal calculation

Tags: lithium-ion, thermal, transient, steady-state, busbar

I am designing busbars for lithium-ion battery pack which is 14-series, 9-parallel combination. We have taken busbars sizes as per the industry standard current density 3A/mm<sup>2</sup>. (Total current 48 A, used busbar size 16 mm<sup>2</sup>.) I need to run the thermal simulation in Ansys software on the busbars to check the temperature rise in busbar exactly after 1 hour of charge/discharge mode (48 A load).

My questions here are:

- What is the thermal steady state analysis and Transient analysis?
- Which state gives the temperature rise in the busbar exactly after 1 hour charge/discharge?
- In general what is the state used in thermal simulation of busbars?
- What are inputs needed to the software to run both the analysis?

Please help here and let me know if you need any additional data.

Comment: I’d think you want a heat sink busbar to something to cool the battery (anode?) whichever has the highest thermal conductance. Not the busbar heat. This slow so steady state and rise time at 10 minute intervals.

Comment: You use ICEPAK?